# Tomcat configuration file ../context.xml seems to be broken. Please make sure it is parsable and valid. See the server log for details

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I'm making a simple connection pool. When I try to run this project I'm having this error. 

**Tomcat configuration file ../context.xml seems to be broken. Please make sure it is parsable and valid. See the server log for details.**

This is my context file. Project name is TomPool1

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/tomPool1"/>
<Resource name="connpool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"

      maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"

      username="root" password="access99" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/connpool"/>

 </Context>
```

I tired lots of question's answers online. But this error is not fixing. Please help me.

**Edit 1**

When I try to validate the context.xml I get this error. 
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Context'. [3]

Comment: Is it whole content from context.xml file ? I think no so please paste whole file content.

Comment: In question you also told your project name is `TomPool1` but you are using `tomPool1` in xml file. BTW have you seen this log **See the server log for details. ?**

Comment: Thank you for your all answers.  
After What I did DiogoSantana told me, I restarted netbeans then I got a jsp error on jdbc driver was missing. So I fixed it. thank you so much.

Comment: @gops this is the whole context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the Context element using the `</tag />` sintax.

Change the line:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/tomPool1"/>
```

To:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/tomPool1">
```

Comment: After What I did DiogoSantana told me, I restarted netbeans then I got a jsp error on jdbc driver was missing thank you so much